# Razor Hidden multiple properties

Tags: c#, razor, model-view-controller

Suppose a have an object obj of type MyTipe with properties: prop1, prop2....prop1 and next razor view

```
@model MyTipe
@using(Html.BeginForm())
{
 @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.prop1)

 @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.prop2)
 @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.prop3)
..............
 @Html.HidenFor(m => m.propn)
<input type="submit/>
}
```

There is a posibility to replace hiddenfor lines with samethink else

Comment: what is your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap all properties, that should be hidden in one object e.g.:

```
public class SomeViewModel
{
    public HiddenModel Hide{get; set;}
    ...
    // other properties
}

public class HiddenModel
{
    public int Prop1 {get; set;}
    public string Prop2 {get; set;}
}
```

and then in your view:

```
@model SomeViewModel
@using(Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.prop1)

    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Hide)
    <input type="submit/>
}
```

Comment: I don't think this would work, how would the value of `HiddenModel` be stored in a `<input type="hidden">`?